# generating random numbers in c++

Tags: c++, random, numbers

I need to generate a random number between 1 and n where n is unsigned int.
If n were int I would simply write `1 + rand()% n`. But unfortunately n is unsigned int. What do you suggest?

Comment: Why it matters if `n` is an unsigned int ? In C++11, there are much better ways to generate random numbers.

Comment: Try `1 + rand() % n`.

Comment: Watch rand() Considered Harmful: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Answer (score 11):

rand() should be avoided whenever possible*.
Use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 engine(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> dist(1, 77);

    for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
        std::cout << dist(engine) << '\n';
}
```

* Because it shares a global state, gets often implemented as a linear congruential engine which has a few drawbacks and it's range is often only 0-2^16. Also, % n where n is not an exact multiple of the range **does not produce an uniform distribution**.

Edit: This might seem like overkill, but technically one would want something like this, since mt19937 needs a bit of "warm up":

```
std::mt19937 create_seeded_rng() 
{ 
    std::random_device rd; 
    std::array<std::mt19937::result_type, std::mt19937::state_size> seed_data; 
    std::generate(seed_data.begin(), seed_data.end(), std::ref(rd)); 
    std::seed_seq seq(seed_data.begin(), seed_data.end()); 
    return std::mt19937(seq); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    std::mt19937 rng = create_seeded_rng(); 
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 100); 

    for (unsigned i = 0; i != 100; ++i) 
        std::cout << dist(rng) << '\n'; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask you once again? My initial problem was to write a function which filled in an array with random numbers in random order. So what I did is

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;
void GenRandArray(int* _result, unsigned int _maxValue)
{
 int i;
 random_device rd;
 mt19937 gen(rd());
 uniform_int_distribution<> dis1(0, _maxValue - 1);
 uniform_int_distribution<> dis2(1, _maxValue);
 for(i = 0; i < _maxValue; i++)
  _result[ dis1(gen) ] = dis2(gen);
}
void main()
{
unsigned int n = 5;
int* ar = new int [n];
GenRandArray(ar, n);
}

Comment: @Igor Why would you want to fill it in random order? Is that really a requirement, because it makes not sense to me.

Comment: See also http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful